# create tiling texture plane xna

Tags: xna

I want to create a plane using xna , similiar to the one in this link so i can add 3d objects above it

http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/plane.html

can anyone guide me or tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to draw is a textured quad: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464051.aspx

Comment: I am not sure this is what I want , I want a tiled texture like the one in the site , but to appear as a ground

Comment: I thought your question was about the construction of the object (the flat surface) to put the texture on. You can apply any texture or graphic to it that you want to like In step 4 where it loads a texture of "Glass", you can substitute any graphic you want there. Unlike 2d, in 3d there is no way to simply place a graphic in 3d space without some sort of vertex/mesh structure to support it. Most of the steps in the link detail how to build that necessary support structure.