# How to Import or Draw a Plane in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm implementing a small software and am having trouble getting the Draw Geometry! How I can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [create tiling texture plane xna](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526717/create-tiling-texture-plane-xna)

Comment: Hmm, the tags save this from being far too vague, but it's still a fairly easy thing to research independently, and there appears to be a lack of evidence of preliminary research...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague. If you want to draw some *vertexes* you have to use the [`GraphicsDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice_members.aspx) draw methods otherwise if you need to draw some *sprites* you have to use the [`SpriteBatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch_members.aspx) draw method.  If you want to import a model you can exploit the draw method of the [`Model`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.model_members.aspx) class.

If you're starting from a scratch I recommend you to give a look to those step-by-step tutorials:

- [Your First Game - XNA Game Studio in 2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893.aspx)
- [Displaying a 3D Model on the Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197293%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)
- [Draw a Textured Quad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb464051%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx)